# 複数のdivを同じスピードで順次positionの変更をしていくと、隙間ができる。

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/tadashi___/pen/mwdOZp

```js
console.clear();
var i = 0;
var _wrapperHeight = document.getElementById('parent2').offsetHeight;
var _child = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
var _past2Index;
var _pastIndex;
var _currentIndex = 0;
var _past2View;
var _pastView;
var _currentView;
var _regulerDirection = true;
var _direction = -1;
// setTimeout(()=>{
//   _direction = 1;
// },15000);
var velocity = 2;
setInterval(function() {
  velocity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  console.log(velocity);
}, 6000);
var _positions = [];
var _heights = [];
var _pause = [];
var _scrollLock = false;
var _scrollTimeout;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  _scrollLock = true;
  clearTimeout(_scrollTimeout);
  _wrapperHeight = document.getElementById('parent2').offsetHeight;
  for (var i_1 = 0, len = _child.length; i_1 < len; i_1++) {
    _child[i_1].style.setProperty('top', _wrapperHeight + "px");
    if (_pause[i_1]) {
      _positions[i_1] = -_wrapperHeight;
      _child[i_1].style.setProperty('transform', "translateY(" + (_positions[i_1] - _heights[i_1]) + "px)");
    }
  }
  _scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    _scrollLock = false;
  }, 500);
});
// currentを update
function updateCurrentView() {
  _currentView = _child[_currentIndex];
}
/**
 * DOMの尻尾が画面内に入ったか。
 * @param  {Element} _el
 */
function isInTail(num) {
  var __y = _positions[num] + _heights[num];
  if (_regulerDirection) {
    return __y <= 0;
  } else {
    return __y > 0;
  }
}
/**
 * DOMの尻尾が画面外にでたか。
 * @param  {Element} _el
 */
function isOutTail(num) {
  var __y = _positions[num] + _wrapperHeight;
  var __h = _heights[num];
  console.log(__y + __h, num);
  if (_regulerDirection) {
    return __y + __h <= 0;
  } else {
    return __y + __h > _wrapperHeight;
  }
}
/**
 * ポジションの更新
 */
function updatePosition() {
  if (_past2View) {
    var _num_1 = _positions[_past2Index] += velocity * _direction;
    _past2View.style.setProperty('transform', "translateY(" + _num_1 + "px)");
  }
  if (_pastView) {
    var _num_2 = _positions[_pastIndex] += velocity * _direction;
    _pastView.style.setProperty('transform', "translateY(" + _num_2 + "px)");
  }
  var _num = _positions[_currentIndex] += velocity * _direction;
  _currentView.style.setProperty('transform', "translateY(" + _num + "px)");
}

function updateCurrent() {
  // currentのtailが画面内に入ったら処理
  if (isInTail(_currentIndex)) {
    // 画面外に出たらpause flagをたてる
    if (!_pause[_pastIndex] && isOutTail(_pastIndex)) {
      _pause[_pastIndex] = true;
    }
    // pastViewがあったら2つ前の履歴に突っ込む。
    if (_pastView) {
      _past2Index = _pastIndex;
      _past2View = _pastView;
      _positions[_past2Index] = _positions[_pastIndex];
    }
    // 現在のcurrentを過去分に
    _pastIndex = _currentIndex;
    _pastView = _currentView;
    _positions[_pastIndex] = _positions[_currentIndex];
    // 次をcurrentに
    var _nextIndex = _currentIndex - _direction;
    // loopするようindexがはみ出た際の調整
    if (_nextIndex > _child.length - 1) {
      _nextIndex = 0;
    } else
    if (_nextIndex < 0) {
      _nextIndex = _child.length - 1;
    }
    // currentを次のdivに差し替え。
    // positionを0にセットしflagをfalseに。
    _currentView = _child[_nextIndex];
    _positions[_nextIndex] = 0;
    _pause[_nextIndex] = false;
    _currentIndex = _nextIndex;
  }
  //
}

function update() {
  if (_scrollLock)
    return;
  updateCurrent();
  updatePosition();
}
// render
function render() {
  // setTimeout(render,1);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  update();
}

function setup() {
  for (var i_2 = 0, len = _child.length; i_2 < len; i_2++) {
    _child[i_2].style.setProperty('top', _wrapperHeight + "px");
    _positions.push(0);
    _heights.push(_child[i_2].offsetHeight);
    _pause.push(false);
  }
  updateCurrentView();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  // setTimeout(render,1);
}
setup();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#parent2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  height: 1000px;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  height: 1300px;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  height: 1500px;
}

.child:nth-child(4) {
  height: 1500px;
}

.child:nth-child(5) {
  height: 1600px;
}

.child:nth-child(6) {
  height: 1000px;
}

.child:nth-child(7) {
  height: 1200px;
}

.child:nth-child(8) {
  height: 1400px;
}

.child:nth-child(9) {
  height: 1500px;
}

.child:nth-child(10) {
  height: 1900px;
}

.child:nth-child(11) {
  height: 1100px;
}

.child:nth-child(12) {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent2">
  <div class="childWrap">
    <div class="child" id="c1">1</div>
    <div class="child" id="c2">2</div>
    <div class="child" id="c3">3</div>
    <div class="child" id="c4">4</div>
    <div class="child" id="c5">5</div>
    <div class="child" id="c6">6</div>
    <div class="child" id="c7">7</div>
    <div class="child" id="c8">8</div>
    <div class="child" id="c9">9</div>
    <div class="child" id="c10">10</div>
    <div class="child" id="c11">11</div>
    <div class="child" id="c12">12</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  (function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = function() {
      var stats = new Stats();
      document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);
      requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
        stats.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(loop)
      });
    };
    script.src = 'https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/master/build/stats.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  })()
</script>
```

上記のcodepenのように、
複数のcを連ねて、画面に入っているもののみtranslateYを上にずらしていく。
divの底辺が画面内にはいったら次のdomを一緒に動かしていく。
という内容を実装しています。

この時、velocityを6秒おきにランダムな速度に変更していますが
velocityの速度が速い時、divとdivの間に不均等に隙間が生じてしまいます。

framerateが低いわけはないのですが、どのあたりの計算を見直すべきかわからず。。
ご教示いただければ幸いです。

下記箇所で3つのdivを、自分の座標+=velocity*侵攻方向として移動しています。

```
function updatePosition(){


  if(_past2View){
    let _num = _positions[_past2Index] += velocity * _direction;
    _past2View.style.setProperty('transform', `translateY(${ _num }px)`);    
  }

  if(_pastView){
    let _num = _positions[_pastIndex] += velocity * _direction;
    _pastView.style.setProperty('transform', `translateY(${ _num }px)`);    
  }

  let _num = _positions[_currentIndex] += velocity * _direction;
  _currentView.style.setProperty('transform', `translateY(${ _num }px)`);    

}
```

上記処理の前に下記も実行していきます。

```
function updateCurrent(){

   // currentのtailが画面内に入ったら処理
   if(isInTail(_currentIndex)){

      // 画面外に出たらpause flagをたてる
       if(!_pause[_pastIndex] && isOutTail(_pastIndex)){
         _pause[_pastIndex] = true;
       }

      // pastViewがあったら2つ前の履歴に突っ込む。
       if(_pastView){
         _past2Index = _pastIndex;
         _past2View = _pastView;
         _positions[_past2Index] = _positions[_pastIndex];    
       }

      // 現在のcurrentを過去分に
       _pastIndex = _currentIndex;
       _pastView = _currentView;
       _positions[_pastIndex] = _positions[_currentIndex];

         // 次をcurrentに
       let _nextIndex = _currentIndex - _direction;

      // loopするようindexがはみ出た際の調整
       if(_nextIndex > _child.length - 1){
         _nextIndex = 0;
       }else if(_nextIndex < 0){
         _nextIndex = _child.length - 1;
       }

         // currentを次のdivに差し替え。
         // positionを0にセットしflagをfalseに。
       _currentView = _child[_nextIndex];
       _positions[_nextIndex] = 0;
       _pause[_nextIndex] = false;

      _currentIndex = _nextIndex;

  }
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決はここに書くでよかったでしょうか？

質問のコードだとそれぞれのdivは個別に座標を管理していましたが

共通の座標を格納した変数を参照することで解決できました。
簡易ですが、下記に該当箇所のコード記載します。
offsetなどは省いています。

```
let _posY = 0; // すべての子要素が共通で参照する座標
let divArray = []; // 動かす子要素を格納した配列
let divOffsetArray = []; // 自分より前の要素分自分をoffsetするための値をいれる


function update(){
    _posY++;

    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        divArray[i].style.transform = `translateY(
            ${_posY + divOffsetArray[i]}
        px)`;
    }
}


function render(){
    requestAnimationFrame(render.bind(this));
    update();
}

render();
```

Answer (score 1):

複数要素を同時に移動する手段は存在しないはずです。アプローチを変える必要があります。

一つ親の要素`<div class="childWrap">`をスクロールさせてやることで同様の効果が得られるはずです。その上で`<div id="c1">`がスクロールアウトした時点で`<div id="c12">`の下にくるように`top`なり`translateY()`なりで位置を調整すればいいでしょう。その方が処理もシンプルになります。

実際、元のアプローチですと`_currentView`、`_pastView`、`_past2View`で縦幅が足りない場合に`_past3View`も扱わなければならないというバグも存在しています。

Comment: 質問に書いたモックだと親要素を動かすで問題ないのですが、
実際のコードだと `.childWrap ` を動かすのでは15fpsもでない場合があるので別のアプローチを探していました。

Comment: @tadashi さん「隙間ができる」という質問に回答したものです。15fpsも出ないというのは本スレッドとは別問題では？

Comment: たしかにご指摘の通りですね。問題点の伝え方を誤っておりました。

ご回答はタイトルにたいしての内容として適切かと思いますのでこのままタイトルを変えずに残しておきたいと思います。